# Is a shul allowed to refuse an aliyah to an "improperly dressed" Cohen or Levi?

Tags: minhag, clothing, kohen-priest, torah-service

Some shuls have a "dress code" requirement in order to receive an aliya. For example, I know of a shul that requires wearing both a button-down (dress) shirt and tie to receive an aliyah.

Suppose that there is only one Cohen in shul, but he is not dressed appropriately according to the shul's rules. Is the shul allowed to refuse to give the only Cohen an aliyah and substitute a Levi or Yisra'el?

Comment: Do you mean he's dressed explicitly Halachicly Kosher but not by the shul's rules, like if the rules say shorts and sandals and he's wearing a frak and a shtreimel? Or he's dressed offensively - everybody with shtreimels and he's with shorts?

Comment: @AlBerko Well, OK, I see that you've exaggerated a bit. But let's say that otherwise, he's dressed halachically fine. E.g., he's wearing a polo shirt, slacks and no tie. In your case, say, he has the shtreiml and button down shirt but no tie.

Comment: From my experience in Meah Shearim, even the shuls that demand from the Shaliach to wear a hat and a coat let Mizrachi Cohanim in shirts to have first Alyah. I think that's the answer - while the Shaliach represents the whole Tzibur, Cohen does not, so they can't prevent him from Alyah.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.24b.15-17?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en

Answer (score 4):

The Maharik (Shoresh 9) writes that the congregation have a right to refuse entry to a Kohen, thus enabling them to give the *aliyah* to someone else.

The Chasam Sofer (OCH 25) rules that once the *Kohanim* agree to establish certain rules (and I think that becoming a member of the Shul implies an agreement to the constitution of the Shul), the Congregation has a right to follow their rules and refuse the Kohen an *aliyah*, even if he is present. [However, the Poskim (See Shu"T Teshuva Me'Ahavo) warn that this should only be used occasionally and when there is a great need, so as not to be *mevatel* the *kovod Kehuna*.]

Comment: And what is Shu”t Teshuva Me’Ahavo?

Comment: Interesting. If you can lin to an online source, I'd appreciate it.